# Executing a Docker image from Azure Container

Tags: azure

How could I run a Docker image from Azure Container Registry using Azure Container Instances?

I already have the container created, with the image, but I have doubts about how to execute that image using Azure Container Instances. I'm having issues with the login, and I haven't been able to find useful documentation regarding this."

Comment: Hi @Jose Ignacio Lavecchia, what was the error that you are facing with the login?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having issues with the login,

First check whether the container registry is in the availability [zone](https://i.imgur.com/SU5G3Sa.png) or not. please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/intro-connected-registry).

- I had created ACR in portal and tried to login before that I enabled the admin user in the **settings < Access Keys**.

[image]

- Open Azure CLI to get login-to ACR. I used `az acr login -n <ACR_NAME>` command for login.

[image]

- Then, I tried using **`docker login <acr_name>.azurecr.io`**. This is used to authenticate the local Docker client with a Docker registry and also to authenticate with public or private Docker image registries, including **Azure Container Registry (ACR).**

[image]

> How could I run a Docker image from Azure Container Registry using Azure Container Instances?

Use the below Command to execute the docker image inside the Azure container.

```
az container create --resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> --name <CONTAINER_NAME> --image <ACR_NAME>.azurecr.io/<IMAGE_NAME>:<TAG> --registry-login-server <ACR_NAME>.azurecr.io --registry-username <ACR_USERNAME> --registry-password <ACR_PASSWORD> --dns-name-label <DNS_NAME_LABEL> --ports <PORTS>
```

**Result:**

[image]

[image]